# Copy files inside of docker image during build

Tags: docker, docker-volume, docker-build

I want to build a docker image that is based on [dockerage/apache-mellon](https://hub.docker.com/r/dockerage/apache-mellon/) which has a volume on `/var/www`. I want to build my web app inside the docker container when I'm building it inside a temporary directory and than copy the files to `/var/www` with the following commands in my Dockerfile:

```
WORKDIR /tmp
COPY . /tmp
RUN ./node_modules/gulp/bin/gulp.js
RUN cp -R /tmp/dist/ /var/www
```

The docker build process finishes without any errors, but the files do not get copied to `/var/www`.
Is there a way to copy files to a location which is declared as docker volume during build?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't do it during the build. The volume is something that interacts with containers, not images. You could create an entrypoint script that copies the files to the volume when the container is launched, but i'm not sure that this would be a good solution

Comment: Does it make a difference if I copy files inside of the image or from the host to the image? Because in my previous solution I just copied the files to the image after I build them on my host and it worked fine with: `RUN mkdir /var/www/[app_name]` `COPY ./dist/ /var/www/[app_name]/` But I don't like this solution much, because you have to do other build steps before you can run `docker build`..

Comment: It does not make a difference. The first time you run a container from this image, the files will be there because the volume gets created. But once it is created, copying files to it from a Dockerfile won't do anything unless you first delete the volume.